# Correct way of putting an SQL SELECT statement into a PHP variabe with another PHP variable as the WHERE

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to add in a PHP variable into a select statement. The SQL is:

```sql
SELECT Nichename 
from niche 
INNER JOIN broker on broker.Niche_NicheID = niche.NicheID 
WHERE BrokerID= (another variable)
```

It works in PHPMyAdmin as a select when I enter the `BrokerID`, the correct `Nichename` shows up. It's a PHP page inside a Wordpress site so I used this code:

```php
$nichename = $wpdb->get_results('
    SELECT Nichename 
    from niche 
    INNER JOIN broker on broker.Niche_NicheID = niche.NicheID 
    WHERE BrokerID
  ')==$broker_id;
```

There is no output when I put this:

```php
<?php echo  $nichename ?>
```

It would like the `Nichename` (e.g. "Travel Insurance") but I get nothing.

I've verified if I do an `<?php echo $broker_id ?>` I get the correct `BrokerID` so I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Maybe just a concatenation issue? Try `$nichename = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT Nichename from niche INNER JOIN broker on broker.Niche_NicheID = niche.NicheID WHERE BrokerID = ' . $broker_id);`, but this is just a guess because I am not familiar with the `$wpdb` API. Also, this might expose you to SQL injection if you're just passing user data to the DB. Be careful.

Comment: I've done that it does pass a result as 'Array'   so the page would say Able 2 Array Review when I want it to say Able 2 Travel Insurance Review.

Comment: @DeniseField i would advise that you learn about prepared statements. They will be a great time-saver on the long run, but most importantly will tool your code against mysql injection attacks , as per [little botty's tale](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: thanks @YvesLeBorg I will look into that.  I didn't design the site but am trying to alter it, I've done a course on SQL but really my knowledge is still very limited.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it thanks to @waterloomatt for pointing me in the right direction, it was a Wordpress specific format I was looking for.

```php
global $wpdb;
$nichename = $wpdb->get_var('
    SELECT Nichename 
    from niche 
    INNER JOIN broker on broker.Niche_NicheID = niche.NicheID 
    WHERE BrokerID = ' . $broker_id
);
```

Comment: This isn't a Wordpress-specific issue. It was just PHP formatting that was wrong. In the code in your question, you were not including the `$broker_id` in the query string, but rather your query was just returning anything with a "truthy" `BrokerID` value, then comparing it to see if it is `==` to `$broker_id`. This isn't what you wanted to do. Glad you got it cleared up.